# How to create matrix of buttons to cover the entire screen

Tags: android, android-layout

How to actually create a matrix of buttons to cover the entire screen programmatically.
What I tried : I am currently able to create buttons but I want them to occupy the entire screen area, they are just occupying top left part

Comment: Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Button[][] buttonArray = new Button[6][4];
        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
        for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
            TableRow currentRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            for (int button = 0; button < 4; button++) {

                Button currentButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                currentButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                // you could initialize them here
//                currentButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
                // you can store them

Comment: The problem is buttons are appearing on the top left part only, and when we use a background colour, we can't differentiate the buttons. I mean the entire top left part in which buttons were present shows the same colour, without showing the borders.

Comment: edit your question and add the code there.It's impossible to read it from comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `TableLayout` or `LinearLayout` too assigning weights in your `Buttons`.

Let's use a `LinearLayout`. This can be done both in xml and in your class. Let's create a 2 by 2 matrix of buttons.

1. Add a `LinearLayout` with any orientation (let's use horizontal)
2. Add 2 `LinearLayout`s inside with opposite orientation of number 1 (in this case we use vertically. Then we set the `width=0dp` and `layout_weight=1` for both to occupy equal spacing)
3. Now we can add our buttons inside the vertical oriented `LinearLayout`s and set their `height=0dp` and `layout_weight=1` for them to have equal sizes.

That's it. using the `TableLayout` is a cheaper way if you have more rows and columns